# Streaming JPEGs from a Cellphone Camera

Tags: java, android, udp

I am trying to stream JPEG frames from the camera to my pc using a udp socket but I am running into some issues.

So I set up a camera and added a callback for the preview frame event:

```
    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)
    {        
        final YuvImage image = new YuvImage(data, mPreviewFormat, mPreviewWidth, mPreviewHeight, null); //Create the Yuv image

        image.compressToJpeg(mPreviewRect, 80, stream); //Compress to JPEG

        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(stream.toByteArray(), 0, stream.size()); //Convert to Bitmap

        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 320, 240, false); //Scale to 320x240

        resizedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream); //Compress back to JPEG

        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(byteArray, byteArray.length, IPAddress, 37654);
        try 
        {
            socket.send(sendPacket); //Send frame to address
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        stream.reset();
    }
```

My problem is that this is taking about 0.2 seconds so my frame rate is about 5 FPS. Is there any way I can speed this up my target FPS is anywhere from 15 to 20 FPS. From my timing tests I believe that the problem may be with `Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(stream.toByteArray(), 0, stream.size());` It seems to be taking the longest time about 0.1 seconds. Is there a way to scale a Yuv image directly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done something similar and ended up moving that into native code and made a JNI call to convert from NV21 and stick onto a circular buffer.

Have a 2nd thread read off the buffer and do the network IO so you can return from onPreviewFrame as quickly as possible.

Even better, copy the nv21 data to the circular buffer and have that 2nd thread do the jpg conversion before sending the data on the network.

by the way, I did this for a video chat client.  It worked well but I've since moved to sending H.263 frames.  It's more efficient than sending JPGs if you are also doing a video chat client.